# Unexpected order of debugger console output

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

When I run my code, the line:

```
WriteLine("Saved Files " + saveFiles + "\n");
```

comes out before the other output lines preceding it. How can I fix this? Code is below.

Here is also a short [video](https://youtu.be/ciwLl7WtFm4) of me demonstrating what I mean too but the code is below. Full code [here](https://github.com/spamproof2010/Memento). Thanks so much.

```
    using DemoMemento;
    using System.Windows;
    using static System.Diagnostics.Debug;

    // This Memento patter will create a caretaker that contains the collection 
    // with all the Statements in it. It can add and
    // retrieve Statements from the collection

    namespace Memento
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {

            Caretaker caretaker = new Caretaker();

            // The originator sets the value for the statement,
            // creates a new memento with a new statement, and 
            // gets the statement stored in the current memento

            Originator originator = new Originator();

            int saveFiles = 0, currentStatement = -1;

            // ---------------------------------------------

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                // Get text in TextBox
                string text = theStatement.Text;

                // Set the value for the current memento
                originator.set(text);

                // Add new statement to the collection
                caretaker.addMemento(originator.storeInMemento());

                // saveFiles monitors how many statements are saved
                // Number of mementos I have
                saveFiles++;
                currentStatement++;

                WriteLine("Saved Files " + saveFiles + "\n");          

                btnUndo.IsEnabled = true;
            }

            private void btnUndo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                if (currentStatement >= 1)
                {
                    currentStatement--;

                    string textBoxString = originator.restoreFromMemento(caretaker.getMemento(currentStatement));

                    theStatement.Text = textBoxString;

                    btnRedo.IsEnabled = true;
                }
                else {
                    btnUndo.IsEnabled = false;
                }
            }

            private void btnRedo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                if ((saveFiles - 1)> currentStatement) 
                {
                    currentStatement++;

                    string textBoxString = originator.restoreFromMemento(caretaker.getMemento(currentStatement));

                    theStatement.Text = textBoxString;

                    btnUndo.IsEnabled = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    btnRedo.IsEnabled = false;
                }

                btnUndo.IsEnabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);` in the UI thread is never the correct thing to do. Also, you need to make your question a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or else your question is likely to be closed. There should be no need to go to a "full code" link for us to be able to help you with your problem, everything should be within the code snippet and should be the smallest possible snippet that re-creates the issue.

Comment: I deleted that sleep line in my post but I guess not fast enough for you to not see it. It was a temp solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The one output code uses `Debug.WriteLine()`, the others use `Console.WriteLine()`. These are two different ways of sending text to the output console which operate in parallel, asynchronously and independent of each other. Using `Debug.WriteLine` is usually faster than `Console.WriteLine` and wins the race unless you delay it by halting at a breakpoint before it is executed.

`Debug.WriteLine` is faster because it directly communicates with the Debugger, while `Console.WriteLine` takes a detour by writing into a pipe that the Debugger has to read from.

Imagine the difference between sending a letter and sending an email. The email arrives earlier than the letter even when it was sent some time after sending the letter.

Solution: Consistently only use `Debug.WriteLine` or only `Console.WriteLine`. Don't mix the two.